# Create an object based on another object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
let Object1 = { id1: { date: '23-01-2023', status: 'completed' }, id2: { date: '02-01-2023', status: 'pending' } }
```

How can I make a new object that has only every key of the object, but also the value of one of the keys on the nested object, like this:

```
let Object2 = { id1: 'completed', id2: 'pending' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` over `Object.entries`, replacing each value with the `status` property of that nested object, then create a new object with `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
let obj1 = { id1: { date: '23-01-2023', status: 'completed' }, id2: { date: '02-01-2023', status: 'pending' } }
let res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj1).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.status]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys of `object1` and use the `reduce` function to populate the new object.

```
const object2 = Object.keys(object1).reduce((res, key) => {
  res[key] = object1[key].status;
  return res;
}, {});
```